# "Uncaught ReferenceError: JQueryValidatorUI is not defined"?

Tags: jquery, grails

"Uncaught ReferenceError: JQueryValidatorUI is not defined" when using jquery-validation-ui plugin ? also Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Here's my order of scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bundle-bundle_jquery-validation-ui_defer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bundle-core_head.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

any clues?

Comment: Do your second two scripts include a version of jQuery within them?

Comment: first one has  qTip - The jQuery tooltip plugin jQuery.validator.addMethod(
...
// amended from existing remote method
JQueryValidatorUI = {
  remote: function(validator, constraint, value,
....

second one has jQuery Tools v1.2.6

Comment: but they don't have the jQuery core, correct? I'm thinking they do, that is the only way you would get the second error.

Comment: I'm not sure, this JQueryValidatorUI is a bit tricky should that validator already exist somewhere or this is a code for defining it... I guess it should be already defined somewhere

Comment: That all depends on whether or not jQuery is being included twice. If jQuery gets included twice, all methods defined on it before the second copy get overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in a plugin just remove JQueryValidatorUI and leave the remote function and call this one instead of JQueryValidatorUI.remote

Answer (score 0):

The qTip script contains `"use strict"` at the top.

That causes this error when the resources plugin bundles the qTip script with the jquery-validation-ui script.

The solution is to add the `var` keyword before `JQueryValidatorUI`.

Submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/limcheekin/jquery-validation-ui/pull/12) to the plugin.

Comment: will try out, it seems like a cleaner solution