# jquery-validation-ui bug?

Tags: grails, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Uncaught ReferenceError: JQueryValidatorUI is not defined”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639269/uncaught-referenceerror-jqueryvalidatorui-is-not-defined)

Any familiar with jquery-validation-ui plugin for grails, when I use it I get the error in chrome script tab, that JQueryValidatorUI can not be found. ("Uncaught ReferenceError: JQueryValidatorUI is not defined")

Here's the code that the chrome is complaining about:

```
// amended from existing remote method
JQueryValidatorUI = {
  remote: function(validator, constraint, value, element, params) { 
            if ( validator.optional(element) )
```

It can be found here:
https://github.com/limcheekin/jquery-validation-ui/blob/master/web-app/js/jquery-validation-ui/grails-validation-methods.js

Thanks in advance,
Mika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed JQueryValidatorUI and left the remote function named as remoteCall and called this one instead of JQueryValidatorUI.remote and it works...